# checkbox multi select add remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have a multiple checkboxes and dropdown options.
When I select a checkbox, I want to apply some class to the select options of dropdown and when I uncheck the same I want to remove that applied class.

The problem, I am getting is since checkbox is multi-select, It doesn't work the way I want.

Say when I check 1st checkbox, I want to apply abc class to option audi and when I uncheck the checkbox remove that abc css class property.

Now when say both the check boxes are selected we should be able to do adding and removing of class at the same time.

```
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r07m18sa/)

Please help.

**Update**: Now, when It gets checked, I am applying the class abc to the dropdowns and also able to remove on uncheck. but it is getting applied to all the select options. What i want is the class should apply to options of the dropdowns.

Comment: there's no JS in your fiddle - write some and then tell us where you are stuck

Comment: Wheres your js code?

Comment: Can you add your js and css in the fiddle?

Comment: i dont see a id attribute in options you need a id attribute so that on click listener of checkbox could add a class or remove it

Comment: sorry guys for not including the js earlier. 
please have a look at the updated fiddle, where I am checking if it is checked or unchecked, now when it is checked I want to apply the class abc to select option and remove the class when unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether a checkbox is selected use `is(':checked')` like this `$('input[name=vehicle]').is(':checked')` it returns boolean - so true or false.

In order to check which one you select use `.val()` like this:

```
$('input[name=vehicle]').val()
```

It returns the value of an checkbox.

You should put id on each option of select in order to put class just on the one option you want.

Here is NEW WORKING [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r07m18sa/3/). Let me know if i helped you. I just suggested the right way so i didnt put the ids on all options ...

So the html code looks like:

```
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="hello" />Hello
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="hi" />Hi
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="bye" />Bye
<br/><br/><br/>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option id="opel" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option id="audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And js like this:

```
$('input[name=vehicle]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Bike'){
        $('#opel').addClass('Bike');
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Car'){
        $('#saab').addClass('Car');    
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked') == false && $(this).val() == 'Bike'){
       $('#opel').removeClass('Bike'); 
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked') == false && $(this).val() == 'Car'){
        $('#saab').removeClass('Car');    
    }
});
```

NOTE: I used jquery because you mentioned it in the tags.

EDIT: Also if you dont want any more classes to be inside of the select you can remove the class attribute with this `.removeAttr('class')`.

EDIT2: Editted the answer to work on options instead of whole select. Provided new jsfiddle.

EDIT3: I used your code from your jsFiddle and rewrite it so it works now as you wanted it in comment.

Comment: please have a look at the updated question and fiddle

Comment: Yes i edited my answer and provided new jsfiddle link. Try it now. Sorry for the inconvenience and let me know if it is now as you wanted it.

Comment: @Suraj Is it working now how you wanted? If the answer is right then please check the question as answered by the right answer. If no, tell me and i will help you. Just let me know :-)

Comment: I am bit confused with this answer, can you check my fiddle. I don't want to apply a signle class on check and remove on uncheck

Comment: So you want to apply the class on all the options then? I understood that you want to add class and remove on certain option, not all of them from this your sentence in question : "Say when I check 1st checkbox, I want to apply abc class to option audi and when I uncheck the checkbox remove that abc css class property."

Comment: when I check Hi, apply class abc to audi, when I uncheck Hi, remove the class abc from audi.
Now when I check Hello without unchecking Hi apply class abc to opel and when I uncheck Hello, remove class abc from opel

I hope this is making sense. :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75905/discussion-between-redrif-and-suraj).

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the category in select box first . Try something like this (updated) on your code :

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="Bike" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="Car" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>

<select id="theSelect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  <option class="Bike" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="Bike" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="Car" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option class="Car" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Car").click(function() {
                    $("#theSelect .Bike").hide();
                     $("#theSelect .Car").show();

                });
                $("#Bike").click(function() {
                    $("#theSelect .Car").hide();
                    $("#theSelect .Bike").show();

                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: please have a look at the updated question and fiddle.

Comment: Ignoring that this does not answer the question asked, hiding `select` `options` does not work properly on almost all browsers (and your code is broken anyway http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r07m18sa/4/). *Who up-voted this?* -1 to compensate